# Laravel redirect back to wildcard value

Tags: php, routes, laravel

Trying to route back to the page with the errors of the validation check. This does not work, what is the proper way to do this?

```
$route = "staff/" . $staff->staff_id;

return Redirect::to_route($route)
->with_errors($validation);
```

Comment: pass it as array my mistake:

    return Redirect::to_route('staff', array($staff->staff_id))
     ->with_errors($validation);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this to redirect back (Assuming Laravel 3)

```
return Redirect::back()->with_errors($validation);
```

or this one

```
return Redirect::back()->with_errors($validation)->with_input();
```

So, no need to mention the route, this is tested on one of my projects.

Comment: is `Input::flash()` necessary while using `->with_input()`? (not related to the question but just wanted to ask here)

Comment: @itachi, No, you'll be using `Input::old('field_name')` in the view.

Comment: Very nice it's `Redirect::back()->withErrors($validation)->withInput()` for Laravel 4